# Как создать программно папку на системном диске в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть часть кода, в которой должна создаваться папка на диске `С`:

```cpp
QDir dir;
dir.mkpath("C:/Program Files/Labs/Результати/");
dir.mkdir(ui->lineEdit_2->text());
```

Но по какой-то причине она не создаётся

Comment: У вас прав не хватает скорее всего, а так, смотрите в окно отладки, там должно быть сообщение о провале, и почему провалился вызов метода. Без этого не понять что произошло.

Comment: Скорее всего так и есть. В окне отладки ничего не пишет.

Comment: Кодировка? попробуй `dir.mkpath(u8"C:/Program Files/Labs/Результати/");` ну и права само собой

Answer (score 0):

запусти программу от имени Администратора